# Unable to delete or archive mail

Tags: mail.app

Periodically, I keep getting an "*x messages could not be moved to the mailbox xxx.  An error occurred while moving messages to mailbox xxx*" popup (see below).  The only way I can resolve is to rebuild my entire mailbox, which takes a long time!  I am connected to an exchange server.  What is the likely cause of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it successfully by rebuilding the mailbox (menu "Mailbox", then "Rebuild".

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause is network slowness when your Mail client is trying to move the messages on the server.

It's unlikely that your mailbox is so corrupt that you keep needing to rebuild and only the passage of time is significant in solving the issue.

If your computer hard drive were so unreliable that errors were creeping in with the same frequency that your Mail deletion happened, you would be noticing other corruption on other files.

Comment: It only happens on certain messages though.. Other (newer and older) messages can be deleted / archived just fine.  Once a message get's 'stuck' it stays stuck.  I have only noticed this with messages that are part of a grouped 'conversation' though..